# Swap min and max numbers in a sequence (C language)

Tags: c

The user inputs one number N where 1<=N<=100
and then inputs N integers between -1000 and 1000.
in the output the max and min numbers in the sequence have to be swapped:

For example:

```
Input:

5

1 2 5 4 5

Output:
5 2 1 4 1
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, numbers,max=-1000, min=1000, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i=0; i<=n-1; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &numbers);
        if (numbers>max) max = numbers;
        if (numbers<min) min = numbers;

        if (numbers==max) numbers=min;
        if (numbers==min) numbers=max;

        printf("%d ", numbers);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that the code from if (numbers==max) is wrong but I don't understand how to swap numbers when the max and min are found. when I assign max to the min then that numbers (which is now min) changes to max again because of the next if statement.

Comment: You can't know what the _max_ and _min_ will be until you have read **all** the numbers. You need one loop to accept all the numbers. Then you need a second loop to discover the _max_ and the _min_. Then you need a third loop to swap occurrences of _max_ and _min_ Actually, you could probably combine the first two loops, i.e. keep track of the _max_ and _min_ while you are accepting the numbers.

Comment: Aside: `i <= n - 1` is a strain on the brain, and can be wrong. Please use `i < n`.

Comment: can use an array?

Comment: single stepping the program in a debugger should open your eyes quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic algorithm for this would be:

> Get no. of inputs
>
> Read inputs
>
> Find *max* and *min*
>
> Iterate over inputs, replacing *max* with *min* and vice versa.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, *numbers, max=-1000, min=1000;

    // Read number of inputs
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // Allocate memory
    numbers = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    // Read array, and simultaneously find max and min
    for (int i=0; i<=n-1; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
        if(max < numbers[i])
            max = numbers[i];
        if(min > numbers[i])
            min = numbers[i];
    }

    // Replace max with min and vice versa
    for (int i=0; i<=n-1; ++i) {
        if(numbers[i] == min)
            numbers[i] = max;
        else if(numbers[i] == max)
            numbers[i] = min;
        printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```